# How to call a PHP file in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a small 'load.php' file which essentially cycles through the images stored on my Pi server, and simply responds with all of the png images.
However, I don't actually know what the correct way to call this file would be in JavaScript, or how to append the results to an HTML element.

load.php:

```
<?php
$dirname = "/var/www/html/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
?>
```

I tied to simply post the results and append them to a Div but that doesn't work:

```
$.post("load.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        imgsDiv.innerHTML = imgsDiv.innerHTML + data;
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? any errors? what is not working as expected? `Doesn't work` is too broad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to send a `post` to server because you are not sending anything.
Try to change your JavaScript code to use `get`:

```
$.get("load.php", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //And you can use jQuery to add data to a element.
    $("#imgsDiv").html(data)
});
```

For this you need to have a html element like this:

```
<div id="imgsDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I cannot get my webpage to access the images on the server. If I run the code locally, the div will display a blank image, but if I run the code from the Pi server it won't display the images. I'm not sure why the server won't respond with the images?

Comment: @sledgewhack Is `load.php` located here `/var/www/html/load.php` or it's in other subfolder of `html` ?

Comment: All the files, and images are located in the same place: /var/www/html/

Comment: If you try to load one image direct form pi is working ok? Without ajax.

Comment: Yes, this works: <img src="load.php?file=/var/www/html/image.png"/> where image.png is a named image saved on the Pi and load.php is: $file = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile($file);

Comment: And simply `<img src="/image.png" >` ?

Comment: The the problem may be the content returned by load.php via ajax. Can add here what load.php returnes? (If the problem is not resolved yet)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a div with id="imgsDiv", try
`$("#imgsDiv").load( "load.php" );`